# How to check if an object has at least one field that is not null?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a set of beans that are generated by a third-party library.

How can I check if each bean has at least one field that is not null?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easily solved using reflection. Just add this method to your bean:

```
public boolean hasAtLeastOneNonEmpty() {
    Class<? extends QueryBean> class1 = this.getClass();
    Field[] fields = class1.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            if (field.get(this) != null) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you asked and add an answer at the same time??? I dont get it....
How should I digest this?

Comment: A way to share knowledge. I just think it can be useful for others and if somebody has a better solution he can post it.

Comment: @jipr311 http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @JulienS.: a better way would have been: "I am trying to achieve this goal. I 've found this does what I need it to do <insert code>, but I am wondering if there is any better, more efficiënt way to do this?" rather than just answering your own 'Question'.

Comment: @Stultuske Not really - if you want a code review, there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @assylias can't open the link, I'm afraid. Next to that: there are tons of "how can I improve this code" on SO. One more won't cause the end of the world.

Comment: @Stultuske fixed the link. There may be tons of them but they are technically off topic.